# Invalid Host Header react app, proxy for development

Tags: reactjs, webpack-dev-server

I have a React, Node app running on a digital ocean. I have proxy for another port defined in `package.json` so that I can run both node and react on the same url. This works fine in development, and the default IP address from digital ocean's server.However, this makes the app crashes on production (more specifically on the domain name) with the error `Invalid Host Header` according to React Official Document (https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/proxying-api-requests-in-development)!, proxy is supposed to only be used in development due to its security risk. However, how do I deal with this? Do I have to remove the proxy and explicitly identify all the request e.g. `axios.get(/example.com/api/posts)`. Some posts mentioned I should add `HOST` to the `.env` or `.env.development` file but it still didn't work.